# How can write this query in sql?

Tags: mysql, sql, database, search

Tables:

TEAMS(***tid***, tname, tcolor, budget)

PLAYERS(***pid***, pname, age, country)

PLAYS(***pid***, ***tid***, season, value)

-(pid references to pid in PLAYERS table)

-(tid references to tid in TEAMS table)

WINS(***wtid***, ***ltid***, season, wscore, lscore)

-(wtid (winner) and ltid (loser) references to tid in TEAMS table)

### --

I have to write query for this:(I tried with "not exist" and "not in" but could not do it.)

Find tid of teams that played with all teams.

Comment: 1) please show what you tried, even if it didn't work. Then we know you _did_ try. 2) Please explain the structure of your database. 3) You've shown us some fields but not explained what the output of the query should be (i.e what the rules are, what should / should not be included, and what the criteria for that are).  Ideally show us some example source data and example of what they query output would be based on that source data. Right now, given only what you've written above, it's not possible to answer your question properly.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This worked for me.

```
SELECT 
     t1.tid
FROM
     teams t1
WHERE
     NOT EXISTS( SELECT 
             t2.tid
         FROM
             teams t2
         WHERE
             t2.tid NOT IN (SELECT 
                     wtid
                 FROM
                     wins
                 WHERE
                     ltid = t1.tid UNION (SELECT 
                     ltid
                 FROM
                     wins
                 WHERE
                     wtid = t1.tid)) AND t1.tid != t2.tid)
```

Answer (score 0):

This will do:

```
SELECT team
FROM (
    SELECT tid team, WINS.ltid otherteam
    FROM TEAMS
    LEFT JOIN WINS ON WINS.wtid = tid
    UNION ALL 
    SELECT tid team, LOSE.wtid otherteam
    FROM TEAMS
    LEFT JOIN WINS LOSE ON LOSE.ltid = tid
)
GROUP BY team
HAVING COUNT(DISTINCT otherteam) >= (SELECT COUNT(tid)-1 AS teamcount FROM TEAMS)otherteams
```

Comment: My MySql Workbench crashed 2 times after trying to execute that query. So it didn't work. I don't know why.

Comment: @yasin if you want more help you'll have to edit your question as I mentioned in my comment above

Comment: Strange. Try put the results of the inner query into a temp table, then apply the outer select to the temp table. This might work.

Comment: Or make the inner query a view and use the outer select on the view. It worked fine for me.